# Imprimir formulário com: 1.foto envida no post 2. id auto incremento gerado no insert do formulário. Em PHP tem como?

Tags: php, formulário, post, imagem, auto-incremento

No momento do cadastro do formulario o usuario vai colocar a foto, ate ai tudo bem.

Meu problema é que preciso imprimir esse formulario ja com a foto e o `id` auto incremento do banco. A ideia era cadastrar os dados 60 campos junto com a foto e no final desse cadastro um botao submit e o evento de imprimir.

Já usei `window.print` e assim nao consigo recuperar a foto nem o `id` so imprimo o que foi digitado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu formulário, ao fazer o envio dele, você poderá usar o `foreach` para cadastrar os dados no banco de dados, conforme o exemplo:

```
foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor){
    echo "No campo $campo tem o valor $valor<br>";
}
```

Com estes valores recuperados e já inseridos no banco de dados, você poderá fazer então a verificação do último id cadastrado, para mostrar na página. Que é este o objetivo.

Vale lembrar que o nome do campo do seu formulário deverá ser o mesmo nome que está no banco de dados.